# Vue.js typescript export modules in folder with index.ts without explicitly defining each module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, module, export

I want to export all default imports from ts files in a folder by using `index.ts` in the same folder. I know I can export all modules in `index.ts` by explicitly exporting each class. But I would like to do it using only `export * from ".";` `in index.ts` file. I also know that I can use this format and import it by using `import * as Modules from "@/modules"` but it imports every module in given folder. I would like to import only required modules. Is it possible ?

Here is an example:

src/modules/ModuleA.ts

```
class ModuleA {
    // ...
}

export default ModuleA;
```

src/modules/ModuleB.ts

```
class ModuleB {
    // ...
}

export default ModuleB;
```

src/modules/index.ts

```
export * from '.';
```

And when I want to import it:

```
// import * as Modules from "@/modules"; // That works but does not recognize imported modules
import { ModuleA } from "@/modules"; // That does not work when index.ts is like in the example
```

I also don't know if my approach is reasonable, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: There's no such thing as `export * from "."`, you need to explicitly list all the modules. There are ways to import multiple module files but they are specific to a bundler and don't make sense in general, e.g. in Vite https://v2.vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import . "but it imports every module in given folder" - this is not true, as this also depends on a bundler. Unused exports can be tree-shaken. Explaining your case could help.